# Mysqli transaction fail to rollback when insert is failed

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, commit, rollback

I have 3 databases, where I need to create database A, then database B, then create the linking database A_B.

I use mysqli transactions in PHP, there is a weird case(this is the first time i use php transactions), where it never rollback when it fails, case like database A fail to insert, but B still created. and A_B created incorrectly.

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($link);
try{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO A (
                     ....)
                    VALUES
                    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?);";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssssssssss",
                   ....
            );
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $param_new_A_Rec = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            
            for($i = 0; $i < $tot; $i++){
     
                            
               $sql = "INSERT INTO B (..)
                VALUES
                    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?);";

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssssssssssss",
                   ...
            );

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $param_new_B_Rec = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO A_B (
                    param_new_A_Rec,
                    param_new_B_Rec,
                     ....                       
              (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssssss",
                    ....
            );
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            }


            mysqli_commit($link);
            
    }catch (mysqli_sql_exception $exception) {

            mysqli_rollback($link);
          
            throw $exception;
            
    }
```

Why if A failed, it never hit the rollback() and it created the incorrect A_B and B data? Did I miss anything here?
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hey, transactions are from the DB not PHP, it doesn't seem you miss something, you can check: 1. some of the [MySQL DB Engines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html) doesn't support transactions, in the link is the doc where you can check if the one you are using support it. 2. Any error not related with `mysqli_sql_exception` will not trigger the `rollback`

Comment: Hello Juan, the engine is InnoDB. I have a case, when I insert date into database A, the field is tinyInt(), i pushed a "false", it failed to create database A, but it continues with database B, and database A_B, which the foreign key links incorrectly, should this trigger mysqli_sql_exception?

Comment: That engine has support, have you try printing something in the `catch` block? to see if the error it's been caught.

Comment: I miss the edit. Just for trying you can put the rollback before the commit that should make no impact; _false_ as data type can be considered `0` and if you have a previous register in a AI colum, `mysqli_insert_id` will return a valid id.

Comment: Please tell us: does the exception ever get raised? Do you have exceptions enabled? Is this code inside a namespace? How do you know A failed if B and A_B was created? It sounds like A completed successfully, otherwise you would get exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I need to add this

"mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);"

Now it is catching the invalid use case:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'boolean_X' at row 1 in yourFile.php